# MySQL Update Query: I Can't find the cause of this Syntax Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to run an update query that modifies the entry in a field via two statements. I keep getting a syntax error 1064 in Workbench. If I run each statement separately in two different queries, they both work. What I  want is for both statements to be in one single query but I keep getting the 1064 error. The code is below.

```
UPDATE `tbloldfurniture`

SET `tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness` = UPPER(`NotesOnOldness`),
SET `tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness` = TRIM(`NotesOnOldness`)

WHERE rwID = 3;
```

What am I doing wrong? The full error message is below:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness` = LOWER(`NotesOnOldness`)  WHERE rwID = 3' at line 4

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
UPDATE `tbloldfurniture`
SET `tbloldfurniture`.`NotesOnOldness` = TRIM(UPPER(`NotesOnOldness`))
WHERE rwID = 3;
```

If you want to set multiple columns, you separate the assignments only with `,`, you don't repeat the word `SET` before each. But in this case you're only setting one column, so you don't need two assignments. Just nest the function calls in a single expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I didn't know that just one SET word is needed.

Comment: That's why there's documentation. When you get an error, read the documentation and it will show you the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I didn't know that the SET word didn't need to be repeated for each assignment. I have tried it and it now works. Regarding nesting the operations/assignments, it might prove confusing/convoluted if any of the assignments is complex. Separating them makes things easier to read for me.  Thanks.